How can you increase sampling density in MRI while maintaining the same FOV?
In MRI, FOV an image is determined by, $FOV = \frac{1}{\Delta k} $. I am trying to understand how you can increase spatial resolution, and by that I mean reduce $\Delta x$ (or pixel width) of the matrix, without increasing FOV (or matrix size). Seeing as $\Delta x =  \frac{FOV}{2n}$ where n is the number of samples take. My question is, for a limited sampling time, how can you increase the number of samples taken, thereby reducing $\Delta k$, while maintaining the same FOV to increase spatial resolution.
Edit: My thought was since the resolution is explicitly dependant on the number of samples, if you increase gradient strength and increase sampling rate, you can increase the number of samples without chaning $\Delta k$, according to $\Delta k = \gamma G \Delta t$

Please spell out the acronyms.
